# how do i format list view column to show currency symbol

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, currency, symbols

I have a ListView on one of the windows project using c#. One of the columns contains currency values. How do I format the List View so that this column presents  the "£" sign (for Pounds Sterling)?

Comment: when i enter £ symbol in text box and click the button save then the list view shows "??" symbol instead of "£" symbol

Comment: Which UI framework are you using? WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET? They all have their own ListView control...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String.Format("{0:c}", CurrencyValue);
```

is supposed to do the trick if you just want currency symbol for the locale of your application. If you're working with multiple currrencies your control of choice has to support Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

you would have to do some thing like giving `UTF-16 (hex)` code of this symbol and do something like this  no need to modify it

```
 listView1.Items.Add(((char)0x00A3).ToString());
```

works for me ........hope it helps

You may want to look at [This](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a3/index.htm)

Comment: newItem.SubItems.Add(fields[3].((char)0x00A3).ToString())           when i am adding this one it will throws an error identifier expected at ((char...

Comment: `newItem.SubItems.Add(fields[3].((char)0x00A3).ToString())` this is wrong. Because `((char)0x00A3).ToString()` returns string and is not within `fields[3]`

Comment: ListViewItem newItem = null;                                     newItem = listViewMs.Items.Add(fields[0]);   newItem.SubItems.Add(fields[1].((char)0x00A3).ToString());

Comment: ` newItem.SubItems.Add(fields[1].((char)0x00A3).ToString());`this is what is wrong.
assuming that by doing above you want to add a "DOT" between value in fields array element no 1 and this symbol you have to do like this 
`newItem.SubItems.Add(fields[1]+"."+((char)0x00A3).ToString());`

If you Understand that field is an array and you are trying to use access operator to access the method or property inside it and `((char)0x00A3).ToString())` Does not exist there that is why you are having error

Comment: if it worked mark it as an answer so that if anyone like you did observes same then he would know that this is the answer

Answer (score -1):

```
String.Format("{0:c}", CurrencyValue);
```

CurrencyValue is not defined error in vb.net